# React dynamic routes and refresh

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am new to react routes and I am writing simple blog collection. I have provided router in index.js

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router>
      <App />
    </Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

I have routes in my app.js

```
  return (
    <div style={{marginLeft:'20px'}}>
      <Route path='/'>
        {loggedUser ? <Bar/> : null}
        {loggedUser ? <h2>Blogs</h2> : null}
        {loggedUser ? <Redirect to='/blogs'/> : <Redirect to='/login'/>}
      </Route>
      <Route path='/login'><LoginForm/></Route>
      <Route exact path='/blogs'>
        <BlogList/>
        {visibility ? <BlogForm/> : null}
      </Route>
      <Route exact path='/users'><UserList/></Route>
      <Route path='/users/:id'><SingleUser/></Route>
      <Route path='/blogs/:id'><SingleBlog/></Route>
    </div>
  )
```

If user navigates to route with id like '/blogs/:id', it works fine. But user can refresh browser and then id disappears from address bar and application drops back to '/blogs'. How to prevent this behaviour?

Comment: I think it's due to the `loggedUser` state of your app, do you have persistant login ?

Comment: try to put `<Route exact path='/'>` instead of `<Route path='/'>`

Comment: I have logged user in localStorage and If loggedUser exixts app.js fetch all data from server and put it to store.

Comment: This change to exact path makes it possible to keep right route in address bar, but then component lose its data. I still have to come up with a solution to that.

Answer (score 0):

it's better to see first [react-router-nesting](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/nesting) it explained perfectly and on the other hand if you have many route create a array

```
const Routes = [
  { 
    component:BlogList,
    path:'/blogs,
    exact:true
  },
  { 
    component:UserList,
    path:'/users,
    exact:true,
    routes:[
      {
       component:SingleUser,
       path:'/:id'
      }
     ]
  {
    component: Order,
    path: '/',
    exact: true,
    routes: [
      {
        component: TabBar,
        path: '/',
      },
      {
        component: Menu,
        path: '/',
        exact: true,
      },
      {
        component: InnerRoute,
        path: '/:name',
        routes: [
          {
            path: '/',
            component: Menu,
            exact: true,
          },
          {
            path: '/info',
            component: InfoRest,
          },
          {
            path: '/favorite',
            component: Favorite,
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

and in the file you wana to use it write following code

```
      <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Switch>{renderRoutes(Routes)}</Switch>
      </Router>
```

import renderRoutes from [react-router-config](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-config)
for routes or map it and return each other